# Loading and displaying HTML+CSS in Java

Tags: java, html, css, parsing

I am Trying to display a Xbox Gamer Card in my Java Program:
Here is a GamerCard: http://gamercard.xbox.com/de-DE/anybody.card

Currently I have the following:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class CardLoader extends JEditorPane {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String[] card = { "http://gamercard.xbox.com/de-DE/", ".card" };
    private static final String styleSheetLink = "http://gamercard.xbox.com/Content/Gamercard/default/gamercard.css";

    public CardLoader(String username) {
        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        this.setEditable(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 135));

        kit.getStyleSheet().addRule(URLCaS(styleSheetLink));
        this.setEditorKit(kit);

        try {
            this.setPage(card[0] +username +card[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String URLCaS(String url){
        InputStream in = null;
        String returner = new String();
        try {
            in = new URL(url).openStream();
            InputStreamReader inR = new InputStreamReader( in );
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( inR );
            String line;

            while ( ( line = buf.readLine() ) != null ) {
                returner += line + "\n";
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returner.substring(3);
    }
}
```

It looks like, it can apply the StyleSheet, but not correctly.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error of some kind? You need to tell us some more here.

Comment: Java/Swing is a "thick client" UI.  HTML/CSS is a "thin client" UI.  Certain Java/Swing components support certain subsets of HTML, but for "true" HTML rendering, you should rely on your browser.  For example, write a Tomcat/JSP UI instead of Swing.

Comment: no, not any errors, it loads everything but does not display it correctly, look here: http://i47.tinypic.com/34y1ct4.png

EDIT: Can I add a JSP file into a java panel? oO

Comment: Q: Can I add a JSP into a Java panel?  A: No.  I was suggesting using JSP *instead* of Swing.

Comment: hmm.. don't want to use jsp, nevermind, i just found out how to put a swt in a jframe, that does my work, don't need the HTMLEditorKit anymore, but now i have another problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Flying-Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), which can render Html to Swing:

> Flying Saucer takes XML or **XHTML** and applies CSS 2.1-compliant
>   stylesheets to it, in order to render to PDF (via iText), images, and
>   on-screen using **Swing** or SWT.

There are some screenshots availalbe here: https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/Screenshots

- [FAQ Swing](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQSwing)
- [Users Guide](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html) ([Rendering to a Swing Panel](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_21))